# How to define wm class for terminal commands in .desktop files

Tags: i3, .desktop

I'm playing around with .desktop files and ended up with this one:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Music Player (cmus)
Comment=Command Line Music Player
GenericName=Music Player
Exec=cmus
Terminal=true
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
```

Everything is working so far.

Now I'm also using i3wm and wanna assign the application to a specific workspace. That's my current configuration:

```
assign [class="^cmus.*$"] 5:
```

Unfortunately the class is not set, as it is not defined yet.

It is working pretty well for other applications which accept an argument, e.g. Firefox:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Twitter Profile - Firefox
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
GenericName=Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Exec=firefox --class="Firefox Social Media" -P "Social Media" %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=firefox
```

With i3wm config:

```
assign [class="^Firefox Social Media$"] 10:
```

Can someone tell me how to define the wm class for .desktop entries starting in a terminal? I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't setup `WM_CLASS` via `.desktop` file because it is up to application to set up its own `WM_CLASS`.

But many applications still allow to change their class using standard methods of their toolkit (GTK/Qt) so most of them will respect `--class` command line option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using the following workaround which I don't consider an real solution.

As I'm using gnome-terminal, the following is possible to set the wm_class:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=gnome-terminal --class=cmus -e cmus
Terminal=false
```

Didn't work using the wrapper *x-terminal-emulator* as it is linked to an wrapper which doesn't support the class.

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually change the class, at least on Ubuntu 22 with default setup (Wayland). `gnome-terminal` seems to ignore the parameter entirely and sets `WM_CLASS` to `gnome-terminal-server`.